# Time Based Workflow

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Requirement: Lead Unread Notification
I have two users, on creation of a lead within two hours if lead is unread a email notification is sent to the owner of the lead.
And if the lead is still unread after 3hours a mail notification to the manager is sent.

I have created a Time based workflow, criteria - based on recordtype and isunread != true
Time based trigger 1 - Mail owner
Trigger 2 - Mail Manager.

Scenario: If Owner Mailing time is suppose 5.00 PM and Owner Mailing time is 5.15 PM

At 5.00 PM, after fulfilling the criteria a mail will be sent to the owner? I hope YES. 
Will the send Mail to manager will also be sent at 5.15 PM even if the record is edited and changed isunread == TRUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Praveen,

here's an extract from this [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US) article

*Time-dependent actions remain in the workflow queue only as long as the workflow rule criteria are still valid. If a record no longer matches the rule criteria, Salesforce removes the time-dependent actions queued for that record.*

what this means for your requirement is, once the lead is marked as read before 3 hours, the Mail Manager action will be removed from the queue and it will not be triggered.

You can check if the Manager Mail time based action will be triggered or not by going to **Setup -> Monitoring -> Time Based Workflow** and filter by your workflow rule name

**refence :** https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_queue.htm&language=en_US